# What is the best way in cocos2d development to load parameters from files?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I was making a tower-defense game and I would like to define all sorts of parameters, like tower/creep attributes, map info, level info and etc., in files so that I could edit my levels and objects of the game without recompiling the project.

As far as I know there are plist files, csv's, xml's and bunch of other options. I'm new to cocos2d but I'm familiar with the concept of data-driven programming, where you abstract out the logic in the code while keeping parameters and data in files.

I will appreciate any useful information, brief intro to pros & cons of different approach

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what really natters are your requirements for editing the data, ie xml is a pain to edit manually with a text editor, plist can be loaded natively but the xcode plist editor sucks for anything but minimal amounts of data

Comment: I use plists, but not the plist editor ... as @LearnCocos2D eludes, i would add 'sucks' is an understatement. Instead, i have a class whose sole purpose is to save the game object model as .plists. When it changes, i just edit that code, run the 'save' method, and pull the model files in the resources folder. When the game starts, it loads the files.

Comment: Thanks @LearnCocos2D! That really helps and is a good start for me. Guess I'll mess around with plist files for a while and see if things work.

Comment: Same for you @YvesLeBorg thanks for the info.